# Why do SVG's replace eachother when stacked on top of eachother in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, svg

My question is rather simple for those who know, but I could not find the answer on the internet. I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wildflower-w7wc8?file=/src/App.js:222-401) to illustrate my issue.

My question is: Why do SVG's replace each other when trying to stack them? And how to prevent this from happening?

I tried wrapping a Box around it but that did not help.

Comment: Your sandbox does not run anything...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wildflower-w7wc8?file=/src/App.js:222-401

Comment: OK, I can see your sample but don't get the question. Your icon components seem to be displayed exactly as they're defined... Where is the problem?

Comment: If you comment out 2 icons, you see that the icons are different, they are not displayed how they are defined. For example, try to uncomment and comment the icons, you will see they change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your components use different images and patterns with the same id (**image0** and **pattern0**). Rename them with **imageVega**, **patternVega**, **imageBio**, **patternBio**, **imageVegan**, **patternVegan** and replace their references.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this about SVG's!